# Emacs + AucteX + Skim (MacOS Sierra) Forward Search Problem

Tags: emacs, mac, forward-inverse-search

Once I upgraded to MacOS Sierra, I started to having problems in forward search in Skim. Backward search functions well. When I press "Cmd + S + Mouse 1" in Skim, it directly goes to the line in Emacs. However, when I add new lines and compiled in the old version Skim highlighted the new lines compiled. However this function does not work anymore.

The problem started after updating to Sierra and upgrading the brew. I tried to reinstall aucTeX, update Skim (1.4.22) however, still could not solve the problem.

In Skim Preferences Pane -> Sync Tab I use
Command : `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/25.1/bin/emacsclient`
Arguments: `--no-wait +%line "%file"`

And in my .emacs file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(TeX-PDF-mode t)
 '(TeX-engine (quote luatex))
 '(TeX-source-correlate-method (quote synctex))
 '(TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
 '(TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
 '(TeX-view-program-list
   (quote
    (("Skim"
      ("/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b -g %n %o %b")))))
 '(TeX-view-program-selection
   (quote
    ((output-dvi "open")
     (output-pdf "Skim")
     (output-html "open"))))
```

Why the backward search is working but not the forward search?

Comment: Perhaps better ask the question to Skim.app mailing list? https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/skim-app-users

Comment: I asked the question in Skim.app mailing list as you suggested. It is told that it would be fixed in the next release of the Skim. Hence need to wait the next version. Thanks for the advice chan1142.

Comment: @sbilmis You comment could be made a self-answer.